# Searching from csv file in python using re.match()

Tags: python-3.x, csv, search

I am trying to put a module in my program that is able to get a string inputted in an entry box and search it in an existing csv file within the same directory. after that, to see if the string has been found, it should either print found or not found. its currently showing the error:

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
import re
import os

win= Tk()
win.resizable(0, 0)
win.title('PRODUCT QUERY')

text_input=StringVar()
int_input1=IntVar()
int_input1.set('')
int_input2=IntVar()
int_input2.set('')


def update():
    import product_updater

def searcher():
    with open('products_database.csv', 'r') as x:
        global word
        word=str[int_input1]
        y=x.readlines()
        dbase_list=list(y)
        for i in word:
            if re.search(i, dbase_list):
                print('found')
            else:
                print('not found')

a=Label(win, text='Scan barcode').grid(column=0, row=0)
b=Entry(win, text=int_input1).grid(column=1, row=0)
c=Label(win, text='Item').grid(column=0, row=1)
d=Entry(win, text=text_input).grid(column=1, row=1)
e=Label(win, text='Sale price').grid(column=0, row=2)
f=Entry(win, text=int_input2).grid(column=1, row=2)
g=Button(win, text='Verify', command=searcher, width=20).grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=1)
h=Button(win, text='Add product', command=update, width=20).grid(column=1, row=3)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you take a look at implementing this with pandas. 
Pandas can read a csv file and return a dataframe which is basically a list of dictionaries with a little more. Finding a string in a pandas dataframe is as easy as a function call.

Answer (score 0):

As Andre suggested, `pandas` is a great library for .csv manipulations.

In this case, to find if a string is included within the table, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

def find_string_csv(file_name, to_find):
    my_csv = pd.read_csv(file_name)

    for col in my_csv:
        if my_csv[col].str.contains(to_find).any():
            print('found it')
            break
    else:
        print('not found')
```

The `.contains` method runs a regex matching option by default. This code will iterate over each columns and check if the string is present in any of them. If it is, it will break after the first occurrence and print `found it`.

Note that it will not match the headers of the columns, so if you have a column named 'abc', running this function with `to_find == 'abc'`, it will not find it. If you want to include the column names in the query, add `header=None` in your `read_csv()` parameters.

Additionally, if you prefer one liners, you can replace the whole `for / else` loop with:

```
print('found it') if my_csv.isin([to_find]).any().any() else print('not found')
```

The `isin` will return a new pd.Dataframe with boolean values of True if equals to `to_find` and False otherwise. Calling `any` on it will give you a pd.Serie where each entry will be a boolean representing whether a given column has a True inside. The second `any` will give you a boolean of True if any column is True, False otherwise.

I find the for loop clearer and easier to read though.